# Prox Operator of a First Order Perturbation (Adding Linear Term to the Function)

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, proximal-operators

Given a function $f$ we can describe its proximal operator as,

$$\mbox{prox}_{\frac{1}{\rho}f}(x) = \arg\min\limits_{u} f(u) + \frac{\rho}{2}\|x-u\|^2$$

How does this change if we introduce a linear perturbation, i.e. we replace $f$ with $f(x) + \langle\mu,x\rangle$? Assuming $f$ is simple, i.e. the prox of $f$ has a closed form, does the perturbation also have a simple prox?

I am curious how easy it is to calculate,

$$\arg\min\limits_{u}f(u)+\langle \mu, u\rangle +\frac{\rho}{2}\|x-u\|^2$$

in particular when $x$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $f(x) = \lambda \|\mbox{vec}(x)\|_{1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Corrected via comments] Sure. The optimality condition for your original prox function is
$$0 \in \partial f(u) - \rho ( x - u)$$
For the perturbation, it is
$$0 \in \partial f(u) + \mu - \rho ( x - u ) = \partial f(u) - \rho ( x - \rho^{-1} \mu - u)$$
So basically, your perturbation is solved by $$\textstyle\mathop{\textrm{prox}}_{\tfrac{1}{\rho}f}(x-\rho^{-1}\mu)$$

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense, I didn't think to consider the optimality condition. Thanks for this!

Comment: Prox operations are one of those areas where working with subgradients really does simplify things.

Comment: Hey, should it be $\mbox{prox}_{\frac{1}{\rho}}(x-\frac{\mu}{\rho})$? I think maybe there is a missing minus sign when you first wrote the inclusion, since we are taking gradient w.r.t. $u$ it should have been $-\rho(x-u)$?

Comment: I believe you are right! Good catch.